# No route found for GET on symfony

Tags: php, symfony, get, http-status-code-404

I have a problem when I create a new view.

I've created a html.twig (validate.html.twig)

```
my routing.yml:
 ads_fi_auth_validate:
    pattern:  /validate
    defaults: { _controller: AdsFiAuthBundle:Auth:validate }
    methods: [POST, GET]
```

and I created a validateAction

> after all this I get a 404 for validate/ GET.

I think I need a command or something like that to tell symfony that I just create a new route to a new view

Thanks a lot guys

Comment: if you run `php app/console router:debug` is your route coming up?

Answer (score 0):

At least in Symfony 2.5 you specify the pattern, with the keyword `path`, not `pattern` so if you change your code to the following:

```
ads_fi_auth_validate:
    path: /validate
    defaults: { _controller: AdsFiAuthBundle:Auth:validate }
    methods: [POST, GET]
```

You should be able to hit your route. That assuming that the bundle and the method exist.

A good way to find out if Symfony is recognizing your route, is by running the console command:

`php app/console router:debug` will list all available routes. There's no need (nor way) to let Symfony know that you just created a new route. Symfony automatically picks them up.

Comment: thanks but this is the only route that doesn't works. I have an others like: ads_fi_auth_auth:
    pattern:  /auth
    defaults: { _controller: AdsFiAuthBundle:Auth:auth }
    methods: [POST, GET] and it works fine. It is just this new view/route

Comment: Run `php app/console router:debug | grep ads_fi*` in the root of your project, you should be able to see all the routes that match your project.

Answer (score 0):

I just find that  I need clear cache, and this solved my problem

```
php app/console cache:clear -e prod
```